# What is the good way to read camera frame and make it a texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I use the ARcore Unity SDK on a Pixel 3. 
I need to read the current frame of the camera at runtime, and make it a texture I can use on ma scene.

I see in the documentation that there a different ways (Frame.CameraImage.Texture, Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes(), TextureReaderApi) but I can't find which one is depreciated or not. 
I check the GitHub issues and try some solutions :

With Frame.CameraImage.Texture :

```
MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = Frame.CameraImage.Texture
```

This works but the texture is updated each frame,so I tried this :

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
Texture2D texture2D = (Texture2D)Frame.CameraImage.Texture;
var pix = texture2D.GetPixels32();
var destTex = new Texture2D(texture2D.width, texture2D.height);
destTex.SetPixels32(pix);
destTex.Apply();
MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = destTex;
```

This work only in instant preview mode, not when I build the app and run it on device. ( I got a white texture)

---

I tried the TextureReaderAPI as follow :

```
void Start()
{
    textureReader.OnImageAvailableCallback += OnImageAvailable;
}

public void OnImageAvailable(TextureReaderApi.ImageFormatType format, int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, int bufferSize)
{
   Texture2D TextureToRender = new Texture2D(width, height, 
   TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
   byte[] Texture_Raw = new byte[width * height * 4];

   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, Texture_Raw, 0, 
   bufferSize);

   TextureToRender.LoadRawTextureData(Texture_Raw);
   TextureToRender.Apply();
   GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = TextureToRender; 
}
```

But I got this error : DllNotFoundException: arcore_camera_utility
GoogleARCore.Examples.ComputerVision.TextureReaderApi.Create, so the callback function is never fired.

---

I also tried the AcquireCameraImageBytes function, and then convert the result from YUV to RGB :

```
private void Update()
{
 using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
 {

         if (!image.IsAvailable)
         {
             return;
         }

         _OnImageAvailable(image.Width, image.Height, image.Y, 0);
     }


}

private void _OnImageAvailable(int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, 
int bufferSize)
{

    Debug.Log("UPDATE_Image"); 

    Texture2D m_TextureRender = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
    bufferSize = width * height * 3 / 2;
    byte[] bufferYUV = new byte[bufferSize];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, bufferYUV, 0, bufferSize);
    Color color = new Color();
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {

            float Yvalue = bufferYUV[y * width + x];
            float Uvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height)];
            float Vvalue = bufferYUV[(y / 2) * (width / 2) + x / 2 + (width * height) + (width * height) / 4];
            color.r = Yvalue + (float)(1.37705 * (Vvalue - 128.0f));
            color.g = Yvalue - (float)(0.698001 * (Vvalue - 128.0f)) - (float)(0.337633 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));
            color.b = Yvalue + (float)(1.732446 * (Uvalue - 128.0f));

            color.r /= 255.0f;
            color.g /= 255.0f;
            color.b /= 255.0f;

            if (color.r < 0.0f)
                color.r = 0.0f;
            if (color.g < 0.0f)
                color.g = 0.0f;
            if (color.b < 0.0f)
                color.b = 0.0f;

            if (color.r > 1.0f)
                color.r = 1.0f;
            if (color.g > 1.0f)
                color.g = 1.0f;
            if (color.b > 1.0f)
                color.b = 1.0f;

            color.a = 1.0f;
            m_TextureRender.SetPixel(width - 1 - x, y, color);
        }
    }

    m_TextureRender.Apply();
    MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = m_TextureRender;
}
```

In instant preview I got this error : EntryPointNotFoundException: AImage_getPlaneData. 
It almost works in build, but something is wrong in my conversion from YUV to RGB I guess, I got this kind of image :
[image]
I can't figure out what is wrong.

I'm running out of solutions, and don't know what is supposed to work and where I'm wrong. Any advice is welcome :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is just change the frame of the camera into a texture?
Make a render texture asset and put it in the "Target Texture" of said camera, if you're looking to make a minimap system (as i'm guessing that's the most common use) you can feed said texture into a raw image, as they take textures

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear enough. 
I need to take a frame frame the phone camera (not the unity one) and make it a texture. I guess I want the same image by ARCore for the background.